# Web scraping - how to extract the type of the links in an URL?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a list of URLs and I have to extract from each URL, the links inside this URL and for each link extract the type of that link (a form, a tracking code, another page on the same site, an external site, etc.).

My question is : Do you think this is feasible with a Python library ?
If Yes, can you give me a starting point ?

Regards.

Comment: Look into requests library.

Comment: Can be done with Scrapy but its a whole framework!

Comment: "a form, a tracking code, another page on the same site, an external site, etc" -- since this is your own classification, you need to do it on your own. I'm not even sure what is the criterion for "tracking code" and what is the difference between "another page on the same site" with URL parameters and "form".

Answer (score 0):

To scrape a page properly,

1. You need some level of understanding of different html and css tags
   and their logics if you are not already familiar.
2. You need to have some understanding of the DOM of the page you are
   trying to scrape as each page will have different structure. For
   that, please open the page, hit F12 (if using Chrome) and then
   select any portion of the page, right click, and then select inspect
   element.
3. Once you have some understanding of the page's structure, you can
   make use of webbrowser, requests and bs4 python libraries to get
   what you are looking for.
4. If you are not already familiar with webscraping with python, I
   will strongly recommend this online book:
   https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/
5. Some example code of say how to directly open a few Google top
   search results of some input text:

   ```
   #Program to open provided number of top google search result pages along with the google page

   import sys, webbrowser, bs4, requests

   if len(sys.argv) > 1:
       number_of_pages = int(sys.argv[1])

   if len(sys.argv) > 2:
       search = "/search?q="+'+'.join(sys.argv[2:])
   else:
       search=""

   webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com"+search)
   google_result_page = requests.get("https://www.google.com"+search)
   google_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(google_result_page.text)

   elems = google_soup.select(".r a")

   number_of_pages = min(number_of_pages, len(elems))

   for i in range(number_of_pages):
       webbrowser.open("http://www.google.com"+elems[i].get('href'))
   ```

Comment: Hi, Thank you. In reality I'm able to extract all the links of an URL but I'm stuck for the second part of the work : Extract the type of the links...

Comment: Not sure if I am following your question properly, 1> This sounds more appropriate question in a web development forum than python scrapping, as basically you are looking for the proper tag in the DOM object, 2> As far my understanding, an <input> tag would take input from an user, but that is a tag inside a webpage, and hence you have to retrieve that child webpage and then have to start scrapping on that child webpage to look for availability of <input> tag. And you should not expect to get that information directly by looking at the child URL if I am not missing something.